# Creating and configuring remote server shares in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, administration, psexec

I took this portion out of a larger script that I'm modifying in order to create and set the permissions to shares on remote file servers. I know this can done with Powershell but there are legacy servers preventing me from using it in this case unfortunately.

My concerns are that I'm not sure you can stack the psexec commands the way that I'm attempting to, that it is processing the parenthesis, and that it may not be passing on the variables to psexec properly. Trying to use call in this case may also add a lot of complexity but may be an option.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set Fs1FQDN=fs1.city.local
set Fs2FQDN=fs2.city.local
set Fs3FQDN=fs3.city.local
set BSTFQDN=bst-fs1.city.local

:: this is set to whatever server is being tested
set UserFileServer=fs1.city.local

set UserName=footest

:: please note that for icacls I am setting up a user I know exists to insure that it can appropriately set permissions

:EMPTY_FUNCTION
    echo.
    echo EXECUTING CREATEUSERFILESHARE
    echo.
    CREATEUSERFILESHARE

:CREATEUSERFILESHARE
    if UserFileServer==%Fs1FQDN%    (
        echo.
        echo Generating user folder on file server %UserFileServer%
        echo.
        psexec \\%Fs1FQDN% -e cmd /c mkdir E:\UDrives\%UserName% ^& attrib +h E:\UDrives\%UserName% /s /d ^& icacls "E:\UDrives\%UserName%" /grant:r "CITY\%UserName%":(OI)(CI)M)
        echo. User folder successfully created
        echo.
        goto CLEANUP
    ) else if UserFileServer==%Fs2FQDN% (
        echo.
        echo Generating user folder on file server %UserFileServer%
        echo.
        psexec \\%Fs2FQDN% -e cmd /c (mkdir E:\UDrives\%UserName% ^& attrib +h E:\UDrives\%UserName% /s /d ^& icacls "E:\UDrives\%UserName%" /grant:r "CITY\%UserName%":(OI)(CI)M)
        echo. User folder successfully created
        echo.
        goto CLEANUP
    ) else if UserFileServer==%Fs3FQDN% (
        echo Generating user folder on file server %UserFileServer%
        echo.
        psexec \\%Fs3FQDN% -e cmd /c (mkdir E:\UDrives\%UserName% ^& attrib +h E:\UDrives\%UserName% /s /d ^& icacls "E:\UDrives\%UserName%" /grant:r "CITY\%UserName%":(OI)(CI)M)
        echo. User folder successfully created
        echo.
        goto CLEANUP
    ) else if UserFileServer==%BSTFQDN% (
        echo.
        echo Generating user folder on file server %UserFileServer%
        echo.
        psexec \\%BSTFQDN% -e cmd /c (mkdir D:\UserHomeDrive\UDrives\%UserName% ^& attrib +h D:\UserHomeDrive\UDrives\%UserName% /s /d ^& icacls "D:\UserHomeDrive\UDrives\%UserName%" /grant:r "CITY\%UserName%":(OI)(CI)M)
        echo. User folder successfully created
        echo.
        goto CLEANUP
    ) else (
        echo.
        echo Invalid selection or no file server specified. Skipping user folder creation...
        echo
        goto CLEANUP

:CLEANUP
    echo.
    echo CLEANUP INITIATED
    exit
```

Comment: there is a line `CREATEUSERFILESHARE` but I guess ot should read `goto CREATEUSERFILESHARE`...

Answer (score 0):

I did get this resolved. So it turns out you don't need to stack remote commands to the terminal in psexec. Since each successful remote command returns an error code it will proceed to the next set of commands. Please note that you will not get any sort of error code back unless you log it on the machine you are performing remote executions on.

A working chunk of the originally posted code would be.

```
:CREATEUSERFILESHARE
    if UserFileServer==%Fs1FQDN%    (
        echo.
        echo Generating user folder on file server %UserFileServer%
        echo.
        psexec \\%Fs1FQDN% -e cmd /c mkdir E:\UDrives\%UserName% 
        psexec \\%Fs1FQDN% -e cmd /c icacls "E:\UDrives\%UserName%" /grant:r "CITY\%UserName%:(OI)(CI)M"
        echo. User folder successfully created
        echo.
        goto CLEANUP
```